# Testing for oneside or twosided document

Tags: conditionals, catcodes

After reading [basics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do) about catcode I started to use conditionals to autoset the preamble. 
Surprisingly when sandwiching the command I do get the error `Undefined control sequence. \if@oneside`, also there is @ within the command:

```
\makeatletter % ??? why does it only work without catcode sandwich
\if@oneside\newcommand{\onetwoside}{oneside} \else\newcommand{\onetwoside}{twoside}\fi  % Autoset var for later according to choosen layout
\makeatother
```

Using the if directly works fine. Where to read up on this?

Comment: I know `\if@twoside`; never heard of `\if@oneside`.

Comment: Without `\makeatletter` the conditional is always false because it tests (with `\if`)  if `@` and `o` are the same. With `\makeatletter` you get notified that `\if@oneside` is not defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you say, if you do not use `\makeatletter...\makeatother` everything "works" (so to say...). And if you call `\onetwoside` you will get "twoside" (try!).

What is going on? Without `\makeatletter...\makeatother` the `@` is not a letter and thus not part of a command. What the human eye reads as `\if@oneside` is for TeX the token list

`\if` `@` `o` `n` `e` `s` `i` `d` `e` and so on.

`\if` starts reading and compares the two following tokens: the `@` (category code 12) and `o` (category code 11). They are definitely not the same, the `\if` conditional evaluates to false, skips the remaining tokens (`neside` and so on) and jumps to the `\else` branch.

If you use `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, `TeX` tries to evaluate `\if@oneside`, which does not exist (LaTeX defines `\if@twoside`), and you get the error.

Comment: Where is the `o` (category code 11) sign from? If \makeatletter is missing what does it evaluate the @ against? Maybe the starting-letter o from oneside?

Comment: @ItsmeJulian see edit